# Do these vectors span $\mathbb{R^2}$?

Tags: vector-spaces

How do I show that $V_1 = (1,1)$ and $V_2 = (-1, 2)$ , $V_3 =(1,4)$ span $\mathbb{R^2}$?

I thought you can express them as a linear combination equaling some fixed $x_1$ and $x_2$, but then I get

$C_1(1,1) +C_2(-1,2) + C_3(1,4)$ =$(x_1,x_2)$

I thought you can take the determinant and if it's not equal to zero, they must span $\mathbb{R^2}$, but determinant functions only work for nxn matrices

Comment: The most direct way is to take an arbitrary vector $(x,y)$ and show it can be written as a linear sum of two of those vectors. Two because $\mathbb{R}^2$ is only two dimensional, so two of the three will be sufficient.

Comment: So to show that all three span $\mathbb{R^2}$ I would have to show the linear combinations of $v_1$ and $v_2$ separate from $v_2$ and $v_3$?

Comment: If $ \{ v_1, v_2 \}$ spans $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $ \{ v_1, v_2, v_3 \}$ must also span $\mathbb{R}^2$ because you write $v_3$ as a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$. Similarly for $ \{ v_1, v_3 \}$ or $ \{ v_2, v_3 \}$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by several ways. One of them is to look at the determinant 
$$\left|\begin{array}{cc}\overbrace{1}^{V_1} &\overbrace{-1}^{V_2}\\1 & 2\end{array}\right|=3\neq0.$$

Therefore the vectors are independent and they span $\mathbb R^2.$

If these two vectors span $\mathbb R^2$, show that $V_3$ is a linear combination of $V_1$ and $V_2$.

For instance, $2V_1+V_2=V_3$ works.

Comment: Don't you mean _since_ these vectors span $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: Yes, _since_ is more precise. It's understandable though...

Answer (score 1):

To make my comments above explicit, find constants $a, b$ such that

$$(x,y) = av_1 + bv_2 = a(1,1) + b(-1,2)$$

This gives two simultaneous equations for $a$ and $b$ which can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Two non-zero vectors $v_1, v_2$ are L.I iff $v_i \neq cv_2$ for some non-zero constant $c$. So clearly you have a basis, and like someone pointed out in the comments, two L.I vectors in $\mathbb R^2$ are a basis for $\mathbb R^2$ ( or for any 2-dimensional space).
IOW: Simon says, two L.I vectors are a basis.